# Android - simple XML encryption and decryption

Tags: android, xml

I am parsing XML from URL in my application and first of all I shlould verify XML signature. Thus, my question is, is there any simple implementation of signing XML and it's verification on android?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean somethin like this?

- Make a request to the webservice that allows you to get the MD5 hash of the XML
- Then get the XML
- Make a MD5 hash from your XML from inside android
- Compare the 2 to verify if you have the entire unmodified XML.

This is a nice string to MD5 converter:

```
private String md5(String in) {
        MessageDigest digest;
        try {
            digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            digest.reset();        
            digest.update(in.getBytes());
            byte[] a = digest.digest();
            int len = a.length;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len << 1);
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                sb.append(Character.forDigit((a[i] & 0xf0) >> 4, 16));
                sb.append(Character.forDigit(a[i] & 0x0f, 16));
            }
            return sb.toString();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, this is it, but up to now, I don't know, how to create MD5 hash for XML

Comment: Do you have access to the webservice ?

Comment: is the xml static or dynamic ( can it change )

Comment: Then make a md5 hash and store that in your application